# Combine two variables to form the identifier for another variable in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, variables, syntax, zsh

I want to be able to take the values of two variables and concatenate them together to form the identifier for another variable in a bash script.

```
  final_answer="we did it"
  one="final"
  two="answer"
  t="${one}_${two}"
  echo ${$t} # would like this to echo we did it; currently give "${$t}: bad substitution"
```

Not sure this is possible but it seems like bash would have this capacity somehow.

Thank you!

Comment: Why is this tagged _bash_ **and** _zsh_?

Comment: Either answer would've been good with me i guess

Comment: @JLaF : Since the answers for bash and zsh will likely look pretty different, I suggest that you ask then two separate questions, one for each language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo "${!t}"
we did it
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Indirection for details.